# Problem with HTML Parser in IE

Tags: javascript, html-parsing

I am trying to create a dialog box that will appear only if the browser selected is IE (any version) however I get this error:

> Message: HTML Parsing Error: Unable to modify the parent container element before the child element is closed (KB927917)

That's all in "Line/Char/Code" 0 so I do not know where is the error. The code I'm using is this:

```
 <script type="text/javascript"> 
  <!--  
  if(BrowserDetect.browser.contains("Explorer"))
  {     
    var Nachricht = 'Hemos detectado que está utilizando ' + BrowserDetect.browser + ' ' +
  BrowserDetect.version + '. Puede que algunas funciones no estén habilitadas. <p></p> Si desea experimentar todo el potencial del portal, por favor intente desde otro navegador (browser). <p></p>Gracias
 showDialog('¡Aviso Importante!',Nachricht,'warning',10);
 } 
 </script>
```

I've noticed if I remove the "BrowserDetect.browser" and .version it removes the error, but I need those to check =/...any ideas will be appreciated =).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You're modifying document while it's being loaded (when browser hasn't "seen" closing tag for this element) . This causes very tricky situation in the parser and in IE it's not allowed.

[IE blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/ie/archive/2008/04/23/what-happened-to-operation-aborted.aspx) has explanation of this.

The solution is to modify another element that's earlier in the document and has been loaded completely (where browser already saw closing tag for it).

BTW: The string `</` is not allowed in `<script>` element. Use `<\/` which is a safe equivalent in JS strings.

Answer (score 9):

I had this same problem.  My issue was that I was calling a Javascript function before the containing `div` was closed.

To fix the problem, I call the Javascript function within the jQuery `ready` event handler:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    some_random_javascript_function();
});
```

Comment: Note to future readers: You don't actually need jQuery to do this - do a search for the `load` or `DOMReady` event handlers

Comment: If you're going to use jQuery, you can use the nice syntax shortcut for document.ready: $(function() {return false;});

Answer (score 7):

Reading the [doc](http://blogs.msdn.com/ie/archive/2008/04/23/what-happened-to-operation-aborted.aspx) linked by porneL, I found a simple workaround for this problem: Adding a parameter 'defer' to the script, all works fine.

```
<script defer=true>
```

Answer (score 3):

Like Sergey Kirienko said: use conditional comments. The code below will only be executed by internet explorer. Microsoft has good information on [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512(VS.85).aspx) page.

```
<!--[if IE]>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
 showDialog('¡Aviso Importante!','message','warning',10);
 </script>
<![endif]-->
```

If you want a specific version you can test for that too:

```
<!--[if lte IE 7]>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
     showDialog('¡Aviso Importante!','Your are using a too old version of Internet explorer. Please upgrade','warning',10);
    </script>
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 3):

Browser sniffing is a kludge that should be avoided when possible. It's best to sniff for the *capability* you want to use. Say you want to execute an XPath expression using document.evaluate(), but you don't know whether it's supported. Instead of sniffing for supported browsers, do this:

```
if (document.evaluate) {
    // go ahead and use it
} else {
    // browser doesn't support it; do something else
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The best way to address IE only are *conditional comments*. You don't even need to use JavaScript. See for example http://www.positioniseverything.net/articles/ie7-dehacker.html.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a little late, but this error also pops up if you are using SWFObject and have 2 divs with the same id.

I had duplicate divs, [with id="flashcontent", thanks to copy&paste].

Solved by renaming the divs with unique ids.

Answer (score 0):

javascript works very easy with navigator.appName. (see http://de.selfhtml.org/javascript/objekte/navigator.htm)
You can create an if-query with this. Very easy, just try it!

Answer (score 0):

A current version of https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js caused this bug on IE8 in one of my sites.

Easiest solution - remove google+.

Easy solution - wrap the code in jquery's document.ready -function or similar:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
     po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';
     var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
});
```