# IE7 gives error

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-7

I have one page which have chat application,wall comments,uploading photos,videos on that page.All is working fine on mozilla firefox,chrome but does not work on IE7.It gives two error

> jquery-1.4.4.min.js
>
> HTML Parsing error.Unable to modify
>   the parent  container element before
>   the child element is closed
>   (KB9278917).

Because of this error my rightside bar of this page is not seeing & chat application is also not working.

Please reply me as early as possible.

Thank you

Comment: It would be helpful if you show us relevant parts of your markup and code. BTW, “jquery-1.4.4.min.js” cannot be a full error message. Perhaps it's just one message? And please don't ask for quick help, answers will not show up sooner if you do so, it's merely annoying.

Comment: can you give the link???

Comment: With the information given I can say: You did something wrong.

Answer (score 4):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301484/problem-with-html-parser-in-ie) discusses the error message you have listed as (2).

> You're modifying document while it's being loaded (when browser hasn't "seen" closing tag for this element) . This causes very tricky situation in the parser and in IE it's not allowed.

Since you're using jQuery, you can probably avoid this by putting whatever code is causing this error in a function called once the page is loaded, using the `jQuery.ready` function:

```
<script>
jQuery.ready(function() {
  // put your code here, instead of just inside <script> tags directly
});
</script>
```